# How to make multiple Deep Linking in two different activity without duplicate the app android

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking, intentfilter

I am using deep linking to share my active link to different applications like WhatsApp.
The problem is I want to share 2 different activities.
Now I am able to share them but if we assume I will share activity A.
After clicking on the link, I will see my application option well that's fine and it will take me to activity A.

But now if I do share to activity B.When I try to click on the link, my application will appear twice at one time, and if I choose what was previously chosen by activity A, it will take me to my activity A.This is a wrong choice, so the requested activity will not work.

See the pictures for clarification this is activity A:

[image]

And this is activity B here problem :

[image]

As you can see my app come at two time.

So what is the problem are there  anyone know solve to this problem help me.

this is manifest code:

```
<!--   1-->
        <activity
            android:name=".FragmanM.MainActivityM" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="============"
                    android:pathPrefix="/post" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="==============="
                    android:pathPrefix="/post" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

<!--    2   -->

        <activity
            android:name=".FragmantA.MainActivityA" >
            <intent-filter >

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="================"
                    android:pathPrefix="/posts" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="==============="
                    android:pathPrefix="/posts" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

this activity A

```
Uri data =getActivity(). getIntent().getData();

        if (data!= null) {
            try {
                post_id =  data.getLastPathSegment().toString();
                getPost(post_id);


            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                post_id=null;
            }



        }


        Bundle bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle !=null){
            if(post_id==null){
                post_id =bundle.getString("mid");


                getPost(post_id);


            }

        }
```

this is activity B

```
Uri data =getActivity(). getIntent().getData();

        if (data!= null) {
            try {
                posts_id =  data.getLastPathSegment().toString();
                getPost(posts_id);



            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                posts_id=null;
            }



        }


        Bundle bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle !=null){
            if(posts_id==null){
                posts_id =bundle.getString("moid");
                getPost(posts_id);


            }

        }
```

Comment: Can you provide us the examples of URLs that you are having?

Comment: Why do you have doubled intent-filters in AndroidManifest?

Comment: Hi brother, I solved the problem of the appearance of two of the application, but now the problem is the two links take me to the same activity @AgentP

Comment: How can I make it one apologize I'm a new app developer @MariuszBrona

Comment: now the problem is the two links take me to the same activity @MariuszBrona

Comment: I have written methods to move users to different activities did you checked it?

Comment: Yes I do it like that : https://a.top4top.io/p_1652abudu1.png @AgentP

Comment: @AgentP Hello brother. Sorry for the delay. I was doing a small sample to help explain the problem Please check the source code of the attachment, make a post from A-B and try the links to view the problem : top4top.io/downloadf-16524whlp1-rar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your activities are providing intent filters but the reason for this is, you are providing a similar path prefix.

What I mean by this is in your first activity i.e `.FragmanM.MainActivityM` you have mentioned

```
 <data
      android:scheme="http"
      android:host="============"
      android:pathPrefix="/post" />
```

And in `.FragmantA.MainActivityA` you have written this

```
 <data
      android:scheme="http"
      android:host="============"
      android:pathPrefix="/posts" />
```

Now take a look at the `pathPrefix`

By the definition and according to documentation pathPrefix :

> The `pathPrefix` attribute specifies a partial path that is matched
> against only the initial part of the path in the Intent object

So when you come across links such as this: [www.yourhost.com/posts](http://www.yourhost.com/posts) the first activity also gets shown and the second one also showed which is expected.

So how to fix this?

Method 1: You can remove intent-filter from your second activity and have single activity handle both paths in this case `.FragmanM.MainActivityM`

and inside that activity make a check-in `onCreate()` somewhat like this

```
        Uri data = getIntent().getData();
        if(data.getPath().startsWith("/posts"))
        {
            //Start Your second activity here 
        }
```

Method 2: Create a whole new activity just to handle links and from there you filter links and move the user to different screens

Comment: Actually, I didn't understand very well what to I do. Sorry, because I am a new application developer.But I have modified the code as follows. Please see the picture:  https://h.top4top.io/p_1652k8qc91.png  but still The links of second activity still take me to the first activity.

Comment: Hey, I checked this link http://marketoman.000webhostapp.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json 
It shows 404 errror

Comment: Hello brother. Sorry for the delay. I was doing a small sample to help explain the problem Please check the source code of the attachment, make a post from A-B and try the links to view the problem :  https://top4top.io/downloadf-16524whlp1-rar.html

Comment: Thank you, brother. I got it now. Your answer was correct. Thank you very much